# Why does Ctrl+Alt+< not work?

Tags: keyboard, alt

My new laptop has a bit of an unusual German keyboard layout where the <kbd><</kbd> key is located to the right of <kbd>AltGr</kbd> (see image below). This makes typing `\|` (<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>ß</kbd> followed by <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd><</kbd>) really really hard (and when typing math-stuff in LaTeX, this happens really really often). Then, I found out that all the <kbd>AltGr</kbd>-combinations can be replaced by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>-combinations. On my machine this works for all <kbd>AltGr</kbd>-combinations EXCEPT <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd><</kbd>.

So my first question is: Why? Why would <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+* work for all keys except <kbd><</kbd>? And my second question is whether it is possible (preferably but not necessarily without external software) to map <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>´</kbd> to <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd><</kbd> to make typing `\|` easier?

[image]

Comment: What are the exact characters you are trying to type - could you give Unicode codes? (Not the characters you are trying to press, but the final ones.) And are you on Windows?

Comment: @harrymc In the LaTeX file I'm trying to type a backslash followed by a pipe character, which results in a norm symbol in the PDF file (a double vertical line with unicode 0x2016).

Comment: Is this on Windows and is typing unicode 0x2016 directly possible in LaTex?

Comment: @harrymc Yes, it is on Windows 10 x64.

Comment: Cross writing. Is typing unicode 0x2016 directly acceptable in LaTex?

Comment: @harrymc It is possible in some circumstances. I tred inserting the double vertical line directly via Alt+8214, but this made the LaTeX file not compile anymore. So I guess, in this case I can't rely on directly typing Unicode characters.

Comment: This is easy using [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/), where you can choose hotkeys to generate the difficult characters or even directly the combination `\|`. Let me know your preferences.

Comment: @harrymc AutoHotkey works great, thank you very much :) I mapped AltGr+´ to "|" via `<^>!VKDD::Send |` in the .ahk file, where `<^>!` stands for AltGr and `VKDD` is the AHK virtual key code for the accent key.

Comment: You are too quick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @harrymc for hinting at AutoHotkey.

I use the following AutoHotkey-script to map <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>´</kbd> on my keyboard to the pipe symbol `|`.

```
#NoTrayIcon
IconVisible := 0

; Map AltGr+´ to send a pipe character "|".
; ^! means Ctrl+Alt and
; VKDD is the AHK virtual key code for my ´-key.
^!VKDD::Send |

; Toggeling the AHK tray icon
; ^!+ means Ctrl+Alt+Shift and VKDD again is the ´-key
^!+VKDD::
  if (IconVisible == 1) {
    Menu, Tray, NoIcon
    IconVisible = 0
  } else {
    Menu, Tray, Icon
    IconVisible = 1
  }
```

I found the AHK virtual key code by running some dummy AHK-script, double-clicking the tray icon and then opening View->Key history.